# Google Maps Marker Clustering not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I got this code from this Snippet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22324298/14071909) that works fine and changed a little bit. But now I wanted to add Marker Clustering to the map like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) but I get nothing to work.
I added

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
```

to the head and

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(markers1,
{imagePath:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

in front of "`markers1 =`" but then I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: e.getDraggable is not a function
```

I don't know why this code is not working here without the marker cluster. On my Page, it works fine.

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
      ["0", "***", ***, ***, "1", "red", "-35", "<h3>***<span style='font-size: 10pt;'>( 12345)</span></h3>"],
      ];


/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4357808, 4.991315699999973);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        clickableIcons: false,
        center: {lat: 50.533481, lng: 10.018343},
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy',
        zoomControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT
        },
      };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var category = marker[4];
    var title = marker[1];
    var color = marker[5];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[7];
    var rotations = marker[6];

    var icon = {
        path: "M320.69 630.86C320.69 630.86 520.91 323.43 520.91 222.4C520.91 73.71 419.43 9.03 320.46 8.8C221.49 9.03 120 73.71 120 222.4C120 323.43 320.34 630.86 320.34 630.86C320.34 630.86 320.46 630.51 320.46 630.51C320.46 630.63 320.64 630.79 320.69 630.86ZM320.57 144.46C358.97 144.46 390.06 175.54 390.06 213.94C390.06 252.34 358.86 283.43 320.46 283.43C282.17 283.43 251.09 252.34 251.09 213.94C251.09 175.54 282.17 144.46 320.57 144.46Z", //SVG path of awesomefont marker
        fillColor: color, //color of the marker
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        rotation:parseInt(rotations),
        scale: 0.06, //size of the marker, careful! this scale also affects anchor and labelOrigin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(310,620), //position of the icon, careful! this is affected by scale
        labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(205,190) //position of the label, careful! this is affected by scale
    }
    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        category: category,
        map: map,
        icon:icon
    });
    

        

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(markers1, {imagePath:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
        //Close InfoWindows
            marker.setVisible(true);
                        if (infowindow) {
                infowindow.close();
            }
        }
        // Categories don't match 
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">***</option>
    <option value="1">***</option>
    <option value="2">***</option>
    <option value="3">***</option>
    <option value="4">***</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I add the specified code to the posted code snippet:

1. `<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>`  to the head
2. `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(gmarkers1, {imagePath:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});` to after the `gmarkers1` array is available (after the loop calling `addMarker(markers1[i]);`

I get the javascript error you report: `Uncaught TypeError: e.getDraggable is not a function`

That is because the constructor takes three arguments:

> ```
> var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
>        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
> ```

(your are missing the first `map` argument)

**Update**

two additional issues with the updated code in your question:

1. the `MarkerClusterer` constructor is in the wrong place (it is outside the `initialize` function, it runs before the markers are created.
2. the `markers1` array is the wrong type to add to the `MarkerClusterer`, they need to be `google.maps.Marker` objects (the `gmarkers1` array)

[image]

**working code snippet:**

```js
var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
  ["0", "Leichlingen", 51.106277, 7.018726, "1", "red", "-35", "<h3>Leichlingen <span style='font-size: 10pt;'>( 42799 )</span></h3><p>Internet: 0 (0%)<p>Social Media: 0 (0%)<p>Dein HSK: 0 (0%)<p>Newsletter: 0 (0%)<p>Banner:  (0%)<p>Zeitung: 0 (0%)<p>Bus: 0 (0%)<p>Radio: 0 (0%)<p>Hören Sagen: 0 (0%)<p>vor Ort:  (0%)<p>Sonstiges: 1 (100%)"],
  ["1", "Stuttgart", 48.7667, 9.18333, "1", "red", "-35", "<h3>Stuttgart <span style='font-size: 10pt;'>( 70327 )</span></h3><p>Internet: 0 (0%)<p>Social Media: 0 (0%)<p>Dein HSK: 0 (0%)<p>Newsletter: 0 (0%)<p>Banner:  (0%)<p>Zeitung: 0 (0%)<p>Bus: 0 (0%)<p>Radio: 0 (0%)<p>Hören Sagen: 1 (100%)<p>vor Ort:  (0%)<p>Sonstiges: 0 (0%)"],
  ["2", "Pfaffenhofen", 49.0644444, 8.9763889, "1", "red", "-35", "<h3>Pfaffenhofen <span style='font-size: 10pt;'>( 74397 )</span></h3><p>Internet: 0 (0%)<p>Social Media: 0 (0%)<p>Dein HSK: 0 (0%)<p>Newsletter: 0 (0%)<p>Banner:  (0%)<p>Zeitung: 0 (0%)<p>Bus: 0 (0%)<p>Radio: 0 (0%)<p>Hören Sagen: 1 (100%)<p>vor Ort:  (0%)<p>Sonstiges: 0 (0%)"],
  ["3", "Bretten", 49.03685, 8.707453, "1", "red", "-35", "<h3>Bretten <span style='font-size: 10pt;'>( 75015 )</span></h3><p>Internet: 0 (0%)<p>Social Media: 2 (13%)<p>Dein HSK: 0 (0%)<p>Newsletter: 0 (0%)<p>Banner:  (0%)<p>Zeitung: 4 (27%)<p>Bus: 4 (27%)<p>Radio: 0 (0%)<p>Hören Sagen: 3 (20%)<p>vor Ort:  (0%)<p>Sonstiges: 2 (13%)"],
  ["4", "Oberderdingen", 49.0655556, 8.8030556, "1", "red", "-35", "<h3>Oberderdingen <span style='font-size: 10pt;'>( 75038 )</span></h3><p>Internet: 0 (0%)<p>Social Media: 0 (0%)<p>Dein HSK: 0 (0%)<p>Newsletter: 0 (0%)<p>Banner:  (0%)<p>Zeitung: 3 (19%)<p>Bus: 1 (6%)<p>Radio: 0 (0%)<p>Hören Sagen: 7 (44%)<p>vor Ort:  (0%)<p>Sonstiges: 4 (25%)"],
];


/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4357808, 4.991315699999973);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    clickableIcons: false,
    center: {
      lat: 50.533481,
      lng: 10.018343
    },
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl: true,
    gestureHandling: 'greedy',
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT
    },
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  
  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    addMarker(markers1[i]);
  }
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers1, {imagePath:'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
  var category = marker[4];
  var title = marker[1];
  var color = marker[5];
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
  var content = marker[7];
  var rotations = marker[6];

  var icon = {
    path: "M320.69 630.86C320.69 630.86 520.91 323.43 520.91 222.4C520.91 73.71 419.43 9.03 320.46 8.8C221.49 9.03 120 73.71 120 222.4C120 323.43 320.34 630.86 320.34 630.86C320.34 630.86 320.46 630.51 320.46 630.51C320.46 630.63 320.64 630.79 320.69 630.86ZM320.57 144.46C358.97 144.46 390.06 175.54 390.06 213.94C390.06 252.34 358.86 283.43 320.46 283.43C282.17 283.43 251.09 252.34 251.09 213.94C251.09 175.54 282.17 144.46 320.57 144.46Z", //SVG path of awesomefont marker
    fillColor: color, //color of the marker
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 0,
    rotation: parseInt(rotations),
    scale: 0.06, //size of the marker, careful! this scale also affects anchor and labelOrigin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(310, 620), //position of the icon, careful! this is affected by scale
    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(205, 190) //position of the label, careful! this is affected by scale
  }
  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    title: title,
    position: pos,
    category: category,
    map: map,
    icon: icon
  });

  gmarkers1.push(marker1);

  // Marker click listener
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function(marker1, content) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(content);
      infowindow.open(map, marker1);
      map.panTo(this.getPosition());
    }
  })(marker1, content));
}
filterMarkers = function(category) {
  for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
      //Close InfoWindows
      marker.setVisible(true);
      if (infowindow) {
        infowindow.close();
      }
    }
    // Categories don't match 
    else {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}

// Init map
initialize();
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;"></div>
  <select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">***</option>
    <option value="1">***</option>
    <option value="2">***</option>
    <option value="3">***</option>
    <option value="4">***</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: That is working fine!
But is it possible to refresh the Cluster when selecting an option from the dropdown?

Comment: I would think so.  What did you try that isn't working? (that is another question)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this because the documentation from google is sparse to say the least.
I have markers created from data returned from the backend that is iterated through in a forEach loop. That data includes

```
{
   location: {
     latitiude: 22,
     longditude: 55,
     [...]
  }
}
```

and some other data.
The forEach builds an array (element comes from from the `data.forEach( (element) => {...`:

```
const coordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(element.location.latitude, element.location.longitude);
const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coordinates,
    map: this.map,
    icon: {
    url: markerIcon,
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(3, 3, 'em', 'em'),
    },
});
```

and the clue in that code sample above is that `MarkerClusterer()` **only accepts a Marker** in it's array, so,

declare a var `markerClusters: any[] = []` somwhere outside the forEach, then add Markers to the clusterMarker array, after the `const marker ...` block of code

```
this.clusterMarkers.push(marker);
```

^ must be Marker objects being pushed.

The other thing is that is not brilliantly documented, but is actually obvious after a bit of thought, is that google docs have you do this:

`const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map, markers });`

The thing here is that MarkerClusterer takes an object, so what I think everyone is actually aiming for is:

```
const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer({ map: this.map, markers: this.clusterMarkers });
```

and the fact your linter will show const markerCluster as never being read is apparently unimportant.

What matters is that you pass in `google.map.Marker()`objects to `new MarkerClusterer({ ....})`